# Is there a way to check whether a string contains unicode characters in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is there a way to check whether a string contains unicode characters in C++

I have a string and I need to validate whether it contains unicode(UTF-8 or UTF-16) characters. If it does I need to convert them to ASCII.
I have some idea about the conversion logic., but need some help in detecting the unicode characters in the string

Comment: You could use a regex

Comment: I don´t want to spoil the fun here, but it´s absolutely impossible to *reliably* determine a data encoding. Every "solution" is based on guessing (percentage of some bytes and chars in some languages, maybe even word recognition etc.etc.)

Comment: Where does this string come from? if it's from a file then the polite thing is that the file will indicate it is unicode by the presence of the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

Comment: For UTF-8 it is very hard to get guaranteed result. UTF-16 can be detected - simply check whether even bytes are zero (at least 1-2). It will not work 100% in case of short string containing only non-latin letters.

Comment: @EdChum A file in general does not need a BOM, why should it? And the BOM as well is valid in pretty much all 1-byte-charsets.

Comment: @i486 ...or in the case that the string is empty and a 1byte-charset termitated with 0 => you´re checking garbage bytes.

Comment: @i486 _If_ you know it is UTF-8, it's very easy to determine whether all of the contents can be represented in ASCII, and even easier to convert to ASCII if they can.

Comment: Ok, but the question is "...detecting the unicode characters in the string". You have to detect and you don't know it is utf8.

Comment: @deviantfan The BOM is more or less conventional for UTF16; it's not that frequent in UTF-8 (although I've seen it).  And while a UTF-8 BOM could be legal ISO 8859-1 (for example), it corresponds to the character sequence `ï«¿`, not a likely start of a file.

Comment: @JamesKanze As you´re saying yourself, xyz is "likely" and more/less "frequent". I just wanted to say that nothing is guaranteed ("...Every solution is based on guessing...")

Comment: @deviantfan Yes.  If the file could be EBCDIC, that would mess things up even more.  The reliability of the guess depends somewhat on where the file came from.  (If it was generated on a Windows or a Unix machine, it won't be EBCDIC:-).)  _Most_ of the time, a file using Unicode will contain some sort of native language text, or something related---not random characters.  And it's hard to imagine a context where the file would start with `ï«¿`; in this case, my _not likely_ is a litote; I can't think of a context where it would start this way.

Answer (score 3):

There's no 100% guaranteed solution.  I'd start by reading the first 100
or so bytes, and try to determine the encoding:

- If the file starts with the three byte sequence 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF, it's
  probably UTF-8.  In this case, drop these three, and process the rest as
  UTF-8, below.
- If the file starts with the two byte sequence 0xFE, 0xFF, it's probably
  UTF16BE.  Drop these two, and process the rest as UTF16BE, below.
- If the file starts with the two byte sequence 0xFF, 0xFE, it's
  probably UTF16LE.  Drop these two, and process the rest as UTF16LE,
  below.
- If every other byte, starting with the first, are mostly 0, then the
  file is probably UTF16BE.  (How much is mostly depends; depending on the
  source of the data, even more than a couple could be sufficient.)
  Process as UTF16BE, below.
- If every other byte, starting with the second, are mostly 0, the it's
  probably UTF16LE (very frequent in the Windows world).
- Otherwise, it's anyone's guess, but processing it as if it were UTF-8
  (without dropping any bytes) is probably acceptable.

As for how to process the file:

- For UTF-8, just check that all of the remaining bytes are in the range
  [0,128).  If they aren't, the file can't be converted to ASCII.  If they
  are, the file *is* ASCII (as well as being UTF-8).  This is also valid
  for most single byte encodings, e.g. all of the ISO-8859 encodings
  (which are still widespread).
- For UTF16BE, every other byte, starting at the first, should be 0, and
  the remaining bytes in the range [0,128).  If they aren't, the file can't
  be converted to ASCII.  If they are, take every other byte, starting at
  the second.
- For UTF16LE, every other byte, starting at the second, should be 0,
  and the remaining bytes in the range [0,128).  If they aren't, the file
  can't be converted to ASCII.  If they are, take every other byte,
  starting at the first.

In all cases, this processing starts *after* dropping any bytes from the
first step.

Finally, you don't say what you are trying to do.  There are encoding
conventions which allow representing all Unicode characters in pure
ASCII; if the ASCII you generate will be processed by code expecting one
of these conventions, then you'll have to process the full Unicode
(including surrogate pairs in the UTF-16) and convert the Unicode to
whatever encoding the target program expects.  C++, for example,
expects universal character names; the representation for `é`, for
example, would be `\u00E9`.  Which means you'd also have to convert `\`
to `\\`.  (As far as I know, this convention only applies to programming
languages, like C, C++ and Java.)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot tell in full generality.

A string is just a sequence of characters (which could be of any size). The *encoding*; inextricably associated with such a sequence; attaches textural meaning to the string.

In Windows, the encoding used is UTF-16 which does allow you to have a punt. It provides the API function `IsTextUnicode` which *can* help. But do take note that there's no guarantee it will work.

Comment: (Side note to avoid confusion: Windows uses UTF16 in many places itself, but that does not mean that every program and file on Windows is UTF16)