# Check if UTF-8 is wchar_t or char?

Tags: c++, windows, unicode, utf-8, zlib

I'm calling zlib API `zipOpen` which create a new zip file from my C++ project. The function signature is 
`extern zipFile ZEXPORT zipOpen (const char* pathname, int append)`.

This call eventually call `fopen` in order to create the file. However, this function doesn't support wide characters, and I'd like to fix it by sending a UTF-8 format (that represented by char* and fit function signature) and before calling `fopen` check if the string contain non ascii characters, if no, call `fopen` as before. if yes, convert to wide string (wchar_t) and call `_wfopen`.

So the question is if there's an C/C++ API that check if UTF-8 formatted string contain non ascii characters ?

Basically I'm looking for a function resembles to `isWide` in the example below.
I'd like to know whether to call `fopen` or `_wfopen` from Windows api with the string represented filename.

```
    std::string toUTF8(std::wstring str)
    {
        std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> converter;
        return converter.to_bytes(str));
    }
    ...
    ..
    .
    std::wstring s1 = L"おはよう";
    isWide(toUTF8(s1).c_str()); //this should return true.

    string s2 = "asdasd";
    isWide(s2); //this should return false. 

    std::wstring s3 = L"asdasd";
    isWide(toUTF8(s3)); //this should return false.

    for s in s1,s2,s3 do : //pseudo code, please forgive me :-) 
        if (isWide(toUTF8(s)))
            _wfopen(s,L"wb"); // create wide char file
        else
            fopen(s,"wb"); // create regular name file
```

and the function signature of isWide :

```
bool isWide(char * s);
```

As stated in the comment below, a similar question was already asked before, but wasn't resolved with standard API.

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check whether a string contains unicode characters in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522421/is-there-a-way-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-unicode-characters-in-c)

Comment: @golobich not a duplicate at all. A UTF8 string is *identical* to a US-ASCII string. That's the whole point of the UTF8 encoding

Comment: Don't use `wstring` or `wchar_t`. They can't even hold the full range of UTF16. They can only handle the UCS-2 subset. C++ uses `char` for UTF8 characters, `u16char_t` for UTF16 and `u32char_t` for UTF32. Even UTF16 can use *more* than two bytes.

Comment: The question itself is wrong. The standard way is to *not care* whether the string contains any bytes above 127. BTW in C++ you *aren't* supposed to mix C file operations with C++ streams. Reading and writing UTF8/UTF16 characters from streams is trivial. It's mixing up the languages like this that creates encoding problems

Comment: Check [String and character literals (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019) from the VIsual C++ docs.

Comment: @panagiotiskanavos, Thanks for your reply, i've narrowed the question check if string contain ascii code only (in order to call `fopen` or `_wfopen`)  is it ok now ?

Comment: No, definitely not. MIxing up streams and C file operations is wrong and *strongly* discouraged. Why don't you use file streams? What are you trying to achieve in the first place?

Comment: If you want to find out whether a file is UTF8 or not, you're doing it wrong. UTF8 strings use 1 or more bytes. You *can't* read a UTF8 file with `_wfopen`, because it always reads 2 bytes. A UTF-8 file with English characters is **identical** to US-ASCII by design

Comment: @panagiotiskanavos, my general problem is using zlib 3rd party library to create file that may contain wide characters. currently zlib uses `fopen` which cannot handle wide char names(this is inherit problem with zlib), so i wanted to change the library code so that it may call _wfopen or fopen depending on the file formatting.

Comment: @IradK and UTF8 characters aren't wide. They can be only 1 byte long, which is why you need to use `char`, `string` and `fstream`, or `char` and `fopen` in C. The C++ standard way is to use *char* for UTF8. SInce you use Visual C++ functions, check Visual C++ documentation on [String and character literals (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019). In your case, if you know the file is `UTF8`, you should use `fopen` in C or

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, your last comment is truncated, perhaps you can write it as an answer ?

Comment: I guess this is on MS Windows? Because normally you use utf8 all the time, and you just send utf8 encoded "international" filename to `fopen`, any modern OS will handle utf8 encoded file names - as the UTF8 is designed to be quite transparent to old code handling ASCII strings, except the length of string in bytes may be larger than actual count of character and various edit functions have understand where particular character starts/ends, but as long as for example you want only to copy the string, or compare it with filename on disk, ASCII designed code will work correctly with UTF8 string.

Comment: but I would expect even windows to be patched up to work like this nowadays? Or are they really stuck in the past that much? Must be difficult to handle these legacy BS all the time.

Comment: Why would you need to check? Just convert it and always call `_wfopen`. Checking first is useless as it doesn't actually serve any purpose.

Comment: @NikosC. do you mean that I should always convert the UTF8 string back to wide string (whether it contain wide characters or not) and _wfopen will work. right ?

Comment: Yes. If you know the source string is UTF8 (note that ASCII ***is*** valid UTF8) then just always convert it.

Comment: @pan: `_wfopen` just opens a file. It doesn't read anything. The `w` in the symbol refers to the *arguments* the function takes. It allows you to open files, passing the file name as a wide character string. Once the function returns, the `FILE*` is no different from any other `FILE*` (e.g. the `FILE*` returned from `fopen`).

Comment: It is trivial to test if a `char` string is valid UTF-8 it not. If it is, convert it as UTF-8 to a `wchar_t` string and pass that `_wfopen()`, otherwise pass the `char` string as-is to `fopen()` and let it fail if the string is not in the user's default encoding.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos "*Don't use `wstring` or `wchar_t`. They can't even hold the full range of UTF16*" - yes, they can, via UTF-16 surrogates.  Windows APIs use `wchar_t` strings for full UTF-16. "*They can only handle the UCS-2 subset*" - true only for a single `wchar_t`, not for multiple `wchar_t`. "*C++ uses `char` for UTF8 characters*" - `char8_t` (and `std::u8string`) in C++20. "*`u16char_t` for UTF16*" - `char16_t`, which is the same size as `wchar_t` on Windows. "*`u32char_t` for UTF32*" - `char32_t`. "*UTF16 can use more than two bytes*" - via surrogates, usable in `wchar_t` strings.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're actually proving my point. Since you mentioned Windows, I posted the link to [the Visual C++ documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019) on purpose. Which explains that UTF8 should be treated as char  And yes, the Windows API uses wchar because it was created in the 90s when the C++ standard library was in its infancy. Nowadays though it's simply bad practice to mix up C and C++ IO functions - If I remember correctly, that was even in the first edition of Effective C++

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos doesn't change what I said. Regardless of whether a UTF-16 string uses `wchar_t` or `char16_t` on Windows, it still needs to use UTF-16 surrogates to handle codepoints outside the BMP

Comment: @RemyLebeau I knew that was in the C++ Core guidelines too [Prefer C++ to C](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#S-cpl)

Comment: @pan: You are missing the point entirely. C++17 has **zero** support for Unicode. There is no portable way to open a C++ [ofstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) on Windows, passing a Unicode path name. You're going to have to be using `std::filesystem` to do so. And even then it's not truly portable, as C++ prescribes no particular character encoding to any given type used to store characters (with the exception of `char16_t` and `char32_t`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to check whether or not there's any non-ASCII characters in the string. If you know it's UTF-8 (note that ASCII is valid UTF-8,) just convert it and always call `_wfopen()` unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your definition of "wide". If you just want to test for the presence of non-ASCII characters, just test for the high bit:

```
bool isWide(const char * s) {
  for (; *s; s++) {
    if (*s & 0x80)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Define "fail"? The input is a UTF-8 string, and OP wanted to detect non-ASCII characters.

Comment: This will fail for *every* non-English character. The range 0-127 holds the basic English characters. Every codepage except US-ASCII uses the range above 127 for local characters. Even the basic Latin1 codepage will fail this test if anything other than letters and numbers are used

Comment: You are technically correct, but I think this function is still correct in the spirit of OP's question. Remember that this test determines whether `fopen` is used or `_wfopen`. If the test returns false, any characters between U+0080 and U+00FF are interpreted according to whatever codepage was set up. For most computers, the byte E9 will be é (CP1252), but on a greek computer (CP1253), it would be ι instead! Being conservative here will result in using `_wfopen` and always producing a é character. (Why OP does not simply _always_ use `_wfopen` is unclear to me)

Comment: Essentially, OP is trying to avoid the problem posed in https://superuser.com/a/1327692/301102

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ah, I see what you meant up there... the thing is the 128..255 extended 8bit ASCII or old DOS code-pages are NOT valid in utf8 encoding. All of those characters should be available in utf8, but with different encoding. If the OP is going from UCS-2 or UTF16 to UTF8, and then wants to know if string is ASCII-only, the code in this answer is ok. If he would try it with any legacy DOS codepage string, then this is invalid, as it's test for utf8 encoded strings. (but makes me wonder why even to fuss with anything, any modern OS just works with utf8 and `fopen`?? I hope...)

Answer (score 1):

You can step through all characters and check if the most significant bit is "1". See: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8, only multibyte characters have that bit set.

```
bool isWide(const std::string& string) {    
    for(auto& c : string) 
    { 
        if(c & 0x80) {
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This will fail for *every* non-English character

Comment: Its true that utf-8 can have a mechanism to cope with invalid utf-8 ( >127 ), but OP uses string_convert to go from wstring to string, its unlikely that will produce invalid utf-8.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what do you mean? In **valid** utf8 string this will **precisely** report all bytes which belong to non-ASCII characters, i.e. what OP was asking. In random data this will of course make no sense, because 128..255 bytes may happen without forming valid utf8 code point.

Comment: What if the text is in the ISO-8859-1 (Latin 1) codepage? This check will fail in every country in Europe and even the US if an accented character (eg `ü`) is encountered. The only thing this test can tell you is that the text is or isn't US-ASCII. You'd need different tests to determine whether it's UTF16 or UTF8 - UTF16 would be easy as every other byte would be `0x00`. With UTF8 though things get difficult as the byte sequences are valid characters in other codepages. `ü` is represented in UTF8 as 0xC3 0xBC which in Latin 1 would be Ã and ¼.

Comment: You can only use heuristics, eg if there are too many Ãs, it's probably UTF8. If you encoutner bytes between 0x00-0x1F and 0x7F-9F, it may be one of the old 437, 850 codepages, or UTF8, as Latin1 doesn't use those ranges.